# Ошибка Visual Studio

Tags: python, telegram-bot

**Делаю телеграм бота (я новичок) вроде сделал все правильно а выскакивает ошибка!**

**Код:**

```
import telebot
import Config

bot = telebot.TeleBot("config.token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет" 
    + message.from_user.first_name + ' ' +message.from_user.last_name
    + ", я бот!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**При запуске идет ошибка!**

```
2021-09-29 21:00:10,304 (__init__.py:663 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found"
```

**Код из файла Config:**

```
token = 'тут мой токен'
```

Comment: `bot = telebot.TeleBot(Config.token)` - без кавычек и с большой буквы

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы пытаетесь использовать бота с токеном "config.token" вместо собственно токена (строки символов). Попробуйте вместо этого просто скопировать токен в вызов метода TeleBot().